# Spring JPA Specification - Generate a Plain SQL Where-Clause

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

we have Spring Hibernate code which generates a Spring JPA data Specification object. This works well (we can use the Specification object to do things like get count). Is there a way to get a plain SQL where-clause from the specification object somehow?

The current code is:

```
// The line below builds the spec based on business logic. Won't go in the details here, but it is working.
Specification<Crash> querySpec = buildQuerySpec(query);
long count = myDataRepository.count(querySpec);

// Here is what I need: a simple plain T-SQL / Microsoft SQL Server where-clause to be used on other disconnected systems. So something like this:
String whereClause = query.Spec.getPlainSQLWhereClause(...); // e.g. weather in ("raining", "cold") and year in (2014, 2015)
```

Reason: the specification object (and its related repository) are used in the main system. Now we have other completely disconnected/separate enterprise systems (Esri GIS system), where its APIs can only use plain SQL where-clause.

P.S. I know there's not much code to work with, so some pointers/guides will be much appreciated.

Comment: No that's not possible. Maybe you should have a look at https://jooq.org that also integrates with JPA

Comment: @SimonMartinelli thanks, it looks interesting. The "Query Lifecycle" part looks promising for my particular problem. And yes, like the jOOQ pages says, I am irritated (as an unenlightened noob) why it is so hard or not possible to get something seemingly so fundamental like a SQL where-clause in Specification/JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: Well, JPA is an abstraction for persistence concerns. If you really want, you can get the full SQL string, but what do you want to do with just the WHERE clause? It strongly depends on aliases of the FROM clause.

Comment: Hi @ChristianBeikov, I need the full where-clause or the full SQL string so I can pass it to the other complete disconnected system (Esri GIS system), where its .NET and JavaScript APIs only uses where-clause to do querying. In my case the FROM clause is not a problem (just one table). If you can point me how to get the full SQL string, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Here you can see how Blaze-Persistence accesses the SQL query behind a JPQL/HQL query: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/blob/master/integration/hibernate-base/src/main/java/com/blazebit/persistence/integration/hibernate/base/HibernateExtendedQuerySupport.java#L116

Comment: Thank you @ChristianBeikov, much appreciated.